# Does "The UK" mean the state or its citizens?

Tags: meaning

When I have expressed criticism towards the UK government saying

> The EU policy is crystal clear ... The UK as usual in their bizarre anti freedom ways

and I got an (obviously) UK citizen pissed at me saying they were personally offended. As English is not my first language -- did I just address the people instead of the state?

Comment: Maybe the folks in the UK are different, but, in that context, I would not feel that "US" was referring to the citizens so much as our (dysfunctional) government.

Comment: I tend to agree with @HotLicks.  Saying "The <country name>" is a reference to the country itself, not to any individual member(s).  Although maybe more appropriate to use "its" instead of "their"?  As in "The UK as usual in **its** bizarre anti freedom ways", to make it crystal clear that you're referring to a single entity?

Comment: Why are these comments and not answers?

Comment: The offense is not necessarily caused by your referring to one or the other. If the UK citizen were a supporter of the current government, he or she might naturally be offended, or even someone more broadly patriotic might feel defensive about an attack on their identity.

Comment: @chx - Because answers take time, and someone's always going to come along and whine that they're not properly documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I have expressed criticism towards the UK government saying

Here *UK* is an adjective describing *government*.

> > The EU policy is crystal clear ... The UK as usual in their bizarre anti freedom ways

Here *The UK* is the United Kingdom of Great Britain, also known as just *The United Kingdom* or just *Britain*.

> and I got an (obviously) UK citizen pissed at me

Here *UK* is an adjective again.

In my usage, *the UK* can't be used to mean *the British*, so I understand your sentence to mean *The UK as a whole*. You are criticising the country as a whole, both the government and the population. That's probably why they were upset with you.

There is possibly confusion because I would have stated it as (if I would say such a thing at all):

> > The EU policy is crystal clear ... The UK as usual in **its** bizarre anti freedom ways

Now it is clear that the sentence is referring to the country (i.e. government) and not necessarily the population as well, although some poeple could still interpret it that way.

Comment: That, or it was just a whinging Pom. :-)